# Linux Mint 18.3, black screen after booting

Tags: linux-mint, boot

I have LINUX Mint 18.3 KDE 64-bit, with Linux 4.10.0-38-generic. Unfortunately after some installing of python packages and update && upgrade, when I am restarting my systems stops after grub on black screen and nothing happens. I am able to enter in recovery mode and tryed to make update && upgrade once again but did not help. Could somebody suggest how I can find the problem and how to solve it?

Result of command  `lspci | grep -i --color 'vga\|3d\|2d'`  :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove those packages? Did you install them to the system  Python install? Modifying the main systemwide Python isn't the best idea. Better to use `venv`.

Comment: I don't know what exactly was changed in core python, and how could I check the integrity of required python packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the history file, /var/log/apt/history.log, I have found that liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64 (1.18.3-0ubuntu1.1) was deleted by `apt-get autoremove`. After reinstalling, all started to work well.
Thanks everybody for suggestions and special thanks you for guru from my job that helped me to find this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue running MATE where mdm and the mate-desktop were somehow uninstalled.
**The solution in short if this happens is to run these commands:**

```
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment mdm
```

http://realtechtalk.com/Linux_Mint_Black_Screen_after_boot_no_graphics_solution-2016-articles